# TestFlight intergration Android

Tags: android, testflight

Unable to receive crash reports on my Test flight account even though application gets crashed.

I integrated the SDK in my application. I did following steps -
1. Integrated SDK in code
2. Used proper Application ID
3. Started session using TestFlight.startSession();
4. Called  TestFlight.sendCrash(121213, "XXX", "YYY"); method 
4. Ended session using TestFlight.endSession(); in one of my destroy() method.

Let me know if I am doing anything wrong or missing anything.

Thanks in advance, your answers will be much appropriated.

Answer (score 0):

Crash sessions should be sent back to TestFlight automatically. There is no need to specify startSession, sendCrash, and endSession. Please contact TestFlight support here (http://help.testflightapp.com/customer/portal/emails/new) so we can further investigate. Please include the URL to the build's permissions page in the email.

Thanks,
Justin (TestFlight Support)

Comment: A single example Android program with each TestFlight feature in it would be great. Also I can't seem to find the home documentation page for `sendCrash()`...